# Rewrite not work properly

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

My problem is whenever I write

```
RewriteRule ^ab-c/([^?]) abc.php?test=$1
```

it works but when I write (no hyphen between b and c)

```
RewriteRule ^abc/([^?]) abc.php?test=$1
```

Rewrite Engine is not work properly.

Comment: What  url are you trying?

Comment: changed formatting and added hint what the difference was between the two lines

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem of options `MultiViews`. Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/file` can be in URL but it will serve `/file.php`.

To turn it off place this line at top of your .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
```